# ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ,ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

Tags: plsql

```
http_req := utl_http.begin_request(t_url,'POST', 

utl_http.http_version_1_1);
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', t_content_type);
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_request));
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IService/GetActive');
utl_http.write_text(http_req, soap_request);http_resp := utl_http.get_response(http_req);
Utl_Http.read_text(http_resp, response_env,32767);dbms_lob.createtemporary(x_clob, false );
bms_lob.OPEN( x_clob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite );
BEGIN
  loop utl_http.read_text(http_resp, l_buffer); 
    dbms_lob.writeappend(x_clob, length(l_buffer) , l_buffer); 
  end LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN others THEN
  IF sqlcode <> -29266 then 
     raise;
  ENDIF;
END;
IF(http_resp.status_code = 200) then 
L_RESP_XML:= xmltype(response_env);

L_RESULTCODE:= l_resp_xml.extract('/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetResponse/GetResult/a:ResultHeader/b:ResultCode/text()', 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"').getstringval();
L_RESULTDESCRIPTION:= l_resp_xml.extract('/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetResponse/GetResult/a:ResultHeader/b:ResultDescription/text()', 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.CRM"').getstringval()

IF (l_resultcode = '0' AND l_resultdescription = 'Successful') then 
    siebel.idc_ir_xml_processing(response_env, err_code , err_mesg);
    IF (err_code <> '00') then 
        error_code := err_code;error_desc := err_mesg;raise error_out;
    ELSE
      error_code := '00T';
      error_desc := l_resultdescription;raise error_out
    ENDIF;
 ENDIF;

utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
error_code := '00';
error_desc := 'SUCCESS';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN error_out THEN 
      error_code := error_code;error_desc := error_desc; ---SQLERRM||' Unhandled Exception';
    WHEN others THEN 
      error_code := '91';error_desc := sqlerrm || ' Unhandled Exception';
    dbms_output.put_line('Error desc:' || error_desc );
END;
```

when we are doing the  testing we are calling the multiple time above Procedure and it will call the HTTP request and get the response. but when we triggering the most of the time we get below error

```
Error desc:ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests
```

Let us know what is the issue in above procedure and how to handle the all the Request connection should close. and how do you make sure that we that issue will not occuer aggain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235679/ora-29270-too-many-open-http-requests)

Answer (score 0):

always use utl_http.end_response to close open connection in case of any exception.

```
http_req := utl_http.begin_request(t_url,'POST', utl_http.http_version_1_1);
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', t_content_type);
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_request));
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IService/GetActive');
utl_http.write_text(http_req, soap_request);
http_resp := utl_http.get_response(http_req);
Utl_Http.read_text(http_resp, response_env,32767);
dbms_lob.createtemporary(x_clob, false );
bms_lob.OPEN( x_clob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite );
BEGIN
  loop utl_http.read_text(http_resp, l_buffer); 
    dbms_lob.writeappend(x_clob, length(l_buffer) , l_buffer); 
  end LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN others THEN
  IF sqlcode <> -29266 then 
     raise;
  ENDIF;
END;
IF(http_resp.status_code = 200) then 
L_RESP_XML:= xmltype(response_env);

L_RESULTCODE:= l_resp_xml.extract('/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetResponse/GetResult/a:ResultHeader/b:ResultCode/text()', 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"').getstringval();
L_RESULTDESCRIPTION:= l_resp_xml.extract('/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetResponse/GetResult/a:ResultHeader/b:ResultDescription/text()', 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/.CRM"').getstringval()

IF (l_resultcode = '0' AND l_resultdescription = 'Successful') then 
    siebel.idc_ir_xml_processing(response_env, err_code , err_mesg);
    IF (err_code <> '00') then 
        error_code := err_code;error_desc := err_mesg;raise error_out;
    ELSE
      error_code := '00T';
      error_desc := l_resultdescription;raise error_out
    ENDIF;
 ENDIF;

utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
error_code := '00';
error_desc := 'SUCCESS';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN error_out THEN
      utl_http.end_response(http_resp); 
      error_code := error_code;error_desc := error_desc; ---SQLERRM||' Unhandled Exception';
    WHEN others THEN 
      utl_http.end_response(http_resp); 
      error_code := '91';error_desc := sqlerrm || ' Unhandled Exception';
     dbms_output.put_line('Error desc:' || error_desc );

END;
```